# Angular Service and HttpClient Type does not exist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get a service working in Angular 5. This is what I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor() { }

  getData() {
    // don't use 'any', type your data instead!
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('./assets/data.json');
  }

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Property HttpClient does not exist on type DataService.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is covered in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: You've accepted the wrong answer! Don't use what @florinache said, instead, go with Rahul's or Chandru's answer!

Comment: You are right...Thanks for letting me know ... now changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this :

readmore about httpClient [here](https://angular.io/guide/http)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    // don't use 'any', type your data instead!
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('./assets/data.json');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to import HttpClient from the module like below

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
```

and you code should be like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    // don't use 'any', type your data instead!
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('./assets/data.json');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider updating the code as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private httpClient: Http) { }

  getData() {
    // don't use 'any', type your data instead!
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('./assets/data.json');
  }

}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Http is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore! That's a very wrong answer!

Comment: Http is going to deprecate better Import HttpClient

Comment: I didn't know that it will be deprecated. @pedromartinez I would suggest considering the suggestions and using a different solution then.

Answer (score 0):

Http Calls have been modified and moved to '@angular/common/http' as HttpClient, since the idea was supported by many developers since its move to '@angular/common/http' from Angular 4.3 and further imports of Http Module from @angular/http is deprecated from Angular 5.Check out the changes here : https://jaxenter.com/road-to-angular-5-133253.html.

Now to your question, you should import HttpClient Module and create an instance of it.
So your code would be like:-

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

```
constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

getData() {
    // don't use 'any', type your data instead!
    return this._httpClient.get<any>('./assets/data.json');
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I didn't have the httpClient listed as *private* in my constructor.

Original Constructor:

```
constructor(
  httpClient: HttpClient
) { }
```

Updated Constructor that resolved the error:

```
constructor(
  private httpClient: HttpClient
) { }
```